# Swapping nodes in singly linked list with a while loop

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list, swap

I'm trying to swap pairs of nodes in a singly linked list such that if the linked list is 1->2->3->4, then what will be outputted is 2->1->4->3. I've managed to output 2->1->3->4 by swapping the first pair but now I'm not sure how to loop over the whole list and perform the remaining swaps. My intuition tells me that I need to use a while loop, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,dataval=None):
        self.dataval=dataval
        self.nextval=None

class Linkedlist():
    def __init__(self,headval=None):
        self.headval=headval

    def printlist(self):
        headval=self.headval
        while headval is not None:
            print(headval.dataval)
            headval=headval.nextval

    def swapnodes(self,headval):
        temp=headval.nextval
        headval.nextval=temp.nextval
        temp.nextval=headval
        self.headval=temp
        

List1=Linkedlist()
Node1=Node("1")
Node2=Node("2")
Node3=Node("3")
Node4=Node("4")
List1.headval=Node1
Node1.nextval=Node2
Node2.nextval=Node3
Node3.nextval=Node4
List1.swapnodes(Node1)
List1.printlist()
```

Comment: In order to swap 2 nodes, the sequence is to first swap whatever points to those 2 nodes, then swap those 2 nodes "next" references. This eliminates having to treat adjacent and non-adjacent nodes differently. If "head" is not a node, it will require special handling if "head" points to one of the 2 nodes to be swapped.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to keep track of three different nodes when doing this pairwise swapping. You need the two nodes that are currently being swapped as well the node prior to this pair. Your current function `swapnodes()` uses `headval` and `temp` to keep track of the two linked list nodes being swapped which suffices for the first swap. However, when you are trying to swap Node3 and Node4, you still need a reference to Node1, the node prior to the current pair being swapped to be able to set Node1.next to Node4. You’re correct that you will need some sort of while loop to accomplish this. Using a dummy head node would also be helpful in generalizing this algorithm.

1. Initialize dummyHead (dummyHead.next = head)
2. Set the prevNode to dummyHead
3. Set the currNode to head
4. Use while loop to iterate the linked list: swap a pair of nodes, update prevNode, update currNode
5. Return dummyHead.next

Comment: why do you need to return dummyHead.next @anusha

Comment: When you create a dummyHead node, you don't care about the value it holds. However, dummyHead.next starts out pointing to the actual head of the list. In this way, you are avoiding having to think about the first set of nodes you want to swap differently than the following pairs and you don't need to worry about saving the new head of the list to return after you have swapped all pairs.